# multiple component react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building an index page of a react app.

The index page contains component A and B, if route is *"/a"* then I want to switch B with C and display A and C. For other routes *"/a/b"*, I want to display other pages.

I have tried the following but it is not working:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={A} >
    <IndexRoute component={B}/>
    <Route path="/a" component={C} />
  </IndexRoute>
  <Route path="/a/b" component={D} />
</Route>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by an informal way.

```
<div>
    <Redirect from="/" to="home"/>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="home" component={Home}>
            <IndexRoute component={IndexView} />
            <Route path="other" component={OtherView}></Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path="about" component={About}></Route>

    </Route>
</div>
```